# Is there any video player that plays Youtube playlists?

Tags: vlc, youtube, mplayer, playlists, minitube

Flash support for Linux is still lacking. Older hardware often performs only poorly when trying to watch youtube videos.

There are several external players  (*VLC*, *mplayer*, *minitube*) that alleviate this problem by offering video playback without flash. But none of them support parsing Youtube playlists out of the box.

**Is there any way I can play Youtube playlists without having to rely on flash?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It turns out there is:

### Playing Youtube playlists using a playlist parser script for VLC

---

**Installation**

Instructions as per the [source](http://opendesktop.org/content/show.php/?content=149909):

- download the [script](http://opendesktop.org/CONTENT/content-files/149909-playlist_youtube.lua) (or copy it and paste it in a new file with the 
  name `playlist_youtube.lua`)
- move the file to `~/.local/share/vlc/lua/playlist/` (current user) or 
  `/usr/share/vlc/lua/playlist/` (all users)

**Usage**

Open up VLC and hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to display the *Open 
Network Stream* dialog. Paste your youtube playlist link into the text field 
and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Make sure the link you copied contains the youtube  playlist identifier (`list=PLxxx`).

---

**Note**: This script relies on VLC's inbuilt youtube parser. As youtube 
changes its system now and then, video playback in VLC might suddenly stop 
working. In that case you will have to update your youtube parser script. 
You can do so with the following commands (credit goes to [phoibos](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197739/vlc-youtube-videos-wont-play-%20anymore)):

```
sudo apt-get install curl
```

(makes sure curl is installed)

```
sudo rm /usr/lib/vlc/lua/playlist/youtube.*
```

(removes old parser)

```
sudo curl "http://git.videolan.org/p=vlc.git;a=blob_plain;f=share/lua/playlist/youtube.lua;hb=HEAD" -o /usr/lib/vlc/lua/playlist/youtube.lua
```

(downloads new parser)